# Using :contains to found a text jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In past questions, i asked for how can hide element's depending text from specific tag i use SPAN, well one answer says that i can use this

HTML

```
<div class="container-a">
                  <div class="container-b">
                    <div class="container-c">
                        <table border="1"style="width:98%">
                          <tr>
                            <td width="220" height="100">
                              1
                            </td>
                            <td width="200">
                              2
                            </td>
                            <td width="300">
                             <div id="step_form_1" class="order-steps">
                              <span>25/01/2016 13:30</span>
                              <div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="120">
                              4
                            </td>
                             <td width="120">
                              5
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    <div class="side-color">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tam">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="container-b">
                    <div class="container-c">
                        <table border="1"style="width:98%">
                          <tr>
                            <td width="220" height="100">
                              1
                            </td>
                            <td width="200">
                              2
                            </td>
                            <td width="300">
                             <div id="step_form_1" class="order-steps">
                              <span>24/01/2016 13:30</span>
                              <div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="120">
                              4
                            </td>
                             <td width="120">
                              5
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    <div class="side-color">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tam">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="container-b">
                    <div class="container-c">
                        <table border="1"style="width:98%">
                          <tr>
                            <td width="220" height="100">
                              1
                            </td>
                            <td width="200">
                              2
                            </td>
                            <td width="300">
                             <div id="step_form_1" class="order-steps">
                              <span>23/01/2016 13:30</span>
                              <div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="120">
                              4
                            </td>
                             <td width="120">
                              5
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    <div class="side-color">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tam">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="container-b">
                    <div class="container-c">
                        <table border="1"style="width:98%">
                          <tr>
                            <td width="220" height="100">
                              1
                            </td>
                            <td width="200">
                              2
                            </td>
                            <td width="300">
                             <div id="step_form_1" class="order-steps">
                              <span>18/01/2016 13:30</span>
                              <div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="120">
                              4
                            </td>
                             <td width="120">
                              5
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    <div class="side-color">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tam">
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

SCRIPT

```
var zxc = 25/01/2016;
var asd = 24/01/2016;    
$(".container-c table tr td div.order-steps").each(function()
    {
       $(this).find('span:contains('+zxc+' '+asd+')').length > 0 ?
          $(this).show() : $(this).hide(); 
    });
```

If i use only one variable the code work's great but if i put two variable, the code is not working,

this is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6x80vabm/16/)

Comment: zxc is a number (0.01240079365079365); not what you want. use a string instead. (add ")

Comment: I think you have to use variable `zxc` and `asd` in OR condition. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6x80vabm/21/)

Comment: use filter => Fiddle => [link](https://jsfiddle.net/6x80vabm/22/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `spans` have only one date at a time, so you need to check them separately

```
//create an array of search text
var searchTxts = [ "25/01/2016", "24/01/2016" ];
$(".container-c table tr td div.order-steps").each(function()
{ 
   //loop through each value
   searchTxts.forEach( function(currentValue){
     //check if this value is contained in the span
     $(this).find('span:contains('+currentValue+')').length > 0 ?
      $(this).show() : $(this).hide(); 
   } );

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping all the divs, you can [`:filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) them aswell.

```
var asd = '25/01/2016';
var zxc = '24/01/2016';

$('.container-c .order-steps').filter(':contains('+asd+'), :contains('+zxc+')').hide();
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/6x80vabm/18/)

Or if it should be the other way around:

```
$('.container-c .order-steps').hide().filter(':contains('+asd+'), :contains('+zxc+')').show();
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE 2](https://jsfiddle.net/6x80vabm/20/)

Answer (score 0):

See you have to use string value instead of number, because the text appearing in the html document is a string. This can be simplified like:

```
var zxc = "25/01/2016";
var asd = "24/01/2016";    
$(".container-c div.order-steps").toggle(function(){
    return $(this).find('span:contains('+ zxc +')').length > 0 ||   
           $(this).find('span:contains('+ asd +')').length > 0
});
```